# Is it possible to determine the number of characters used for a password used to encrypt a file with AES 128?

Tags: aes, password-hashing, password-based-encryption

I lost a password for an ethereum wallet at the end of 2016. Computer immediately shutdown and password was not recoverable.

I know there are many potential avenues for narrowing my search for what my password could have been, but I am wondering if the number of characters can be determined from the encrypted file?

I dont know if this would make a difference but it was an ethereum wallet, using Geth

Answer (score 3):

No. Password cannot be used to encrypt anything directly unless it is exactly of a certain size, and then it will be likely weak. Encryption passwords are hashed, with a slow hash hopefully, and the output is used as key.

Comment: ok so the specific program used for hashing is up to what ever the developers decided to use with their client? (I'm assuming hashing isnt a singular process like there is different types of hashing)

Comment: And so it looks like there would never be a way to determine the starting size of the password?

Comment: Yes, the concrete program chooses the hashing. If they follow recommendations, nowadays it should be PBKDF2 or preferably Argon2

Comment: Or it it specified in a protocol. Or the stored data has metadata for the chosen hashing details.

Comment: If at that time they had not used PBKDF2 or preferably Argon2 might there be some hope for gleaning some information about the password, like length?

Comment: No, length would not be easier to guess than guessing the password itself, unless they did something very stupid. But 'etherium wallet, end of 2016', I bet they did it properly, with a slow hash, maybe not among the recommended but still very strong. Remembering the password is you best bet. If you did not invent it but it was automatically chosen (by password manager, for example), I am not optimistic. BTW even if you knew the length that will not help a lot (in general, it halves the needed guesses).  If you can break it knowing the length, you can break it not knowing it. And vice versa.

Comment: hm, i wonder if i could set enough parameters for how i poked the keyboard to make it at all reasonable that i find it.

Comment: i geuss ill wait for a quantum computer .. : (

Comment: The whole point of wallets is that they are secure. Unless they after all did something wrong AND you have the capability of NSA OR you entered very short password, I don't think there is any realistic option other than somehow remembering it.

Comment: for some reason im irritated by this statement "The whole point of wallets is that they are secure." but i appreciate your help.

Comment: anyway yes, it comes down to somehow bruteforcing password by finding parameters for what it could have been, retrieving from ssd tho more likely to be impossible as not a HHD, and waiting on quatum computers.

Comment: I can imagine your frustration, but if you could figure out something about the password, bad guys can too, and they are expected to have much larger resources. This is what this means.

Comment: preaching to the choir

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to determine the password used to encrypt the file by analyzing the file.

AES is a block cypher which uses a fixed length encryption key (which is not your password) to create fixed blocks of encrypted bytes. This means the designers of the cryptographic system you used had to take a variable length password submitted by the user (which is not very random because the characters in the password are represented on a computer by a small range of bytes) and convert it to a fixed length encryption key which is very random (a.k.a has high entropy). This transformation often happen by the application of many hashes (in a process known as Password Based Key Derivation Functions, PBKDF). Hashes are transformations (a.k.a. functions) which take in a string of byes of any size and produce a fixed length output. Hashes also have the desired property that this transformation can only happen in one direction. It would be too difficult to take the output of a hash and determine what input to the hash function created it.

If I was in this situation I would investigate to see if the application I used was Open Source. I would then investigate the software repository (most likely hosted on Gitlab or GitHub) and look at the code responsible for the encryption. I would then use that code to create a small decryption program which attempts to decrypt the file and then checks the output. This of course assumes that the amount of currency recovered was worth the time.